# Marcar en un fichero, cuando se presiona una letra

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy tratando de que cuando presione la letra S, el archivo de texto que he cargado ponga una S al final de la linea actual. Es decir, si he presionado 5 veces la S, el contador debe de ser igual a 5, por lo tanto debe marcarse hasta la linea 5 del fichero de texto. Cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
    <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="archivo" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" />
    </form>

        <?php
            $ultimo_archivo;

            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'])) {
                    $ultimo_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $ultimo_archivo);
                    $lineas_archivo = file($ultimo_archivo);
                        ?>
                    <script>
                        let cont = 0; // Pone el contador a 0;
                        const lineas = <?php echo json_encode($lineas_archivo); ?>;

                        <?php
                        foreach($lineas_archivo as &$l) {
                            $l = str_replace("\r\n", " S\r\n", $l);
                        }

                        fopen($ultimo_archivo, "w");
                        file_put_contents($ultimo_archivo, implode("", $lineas_archivo));

                        //Borra el archivo despues de leer todas las lineas
                        //unlink($ultimo_archivo);

                        //fopen('localhost/prueba/'.$ultimo_archivo, 'r');

                        ?>

                        //Añade la primera linea
                        document.body.append(lineas[cont++]);
                        document.body.innerHTML += "<br>";
                        //Añade un evento cuando se pulse la letra S
                        addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
                            if(event.key === "s" || event.key === "S") {
                                if(cont <= lineas.length-1) {
                                    //Agrega la siguiente linea e incrementa el contador

                                    //Modifica la linea y agrega una S al final
                                    linea_actual = lineas[cont++];
                                    document.body.innerHTML += "<br>";

                                    document.body.append(linea_actual);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    </script>
                <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya que tienes un form, no te serviría poner un input donde puedan meter esas "S" y luego controlar con js que solo sean "s", Si no lo que se me ocurre es que con un evento js de onclick, mandes petición ajax por cada click en la s. Y luego con php te encarges de añadir esas letras, pero deberías tener o al menos saber previamente el fichero en el servidor.

Comment: De todas formas podrías poner un ejemplo sencillo de como debería verse el resultado en el archivo de texto? Aunque sea inventate el contenido del archivo :-) con tres o cuatro lineas inventadas con lo de la S.
Eso sería de gran ayuda y daría a entender mejor lo que pides.

Comment: @Lorthas mira, esta casi hecho! de nuevo te agradezco, y estaria casi hecho, este es  el resultado que esperaria al final. http://i.imgur.com/uKjHwMl.jpg Se pone una S en el archivo, de acuerdo al cont que se genera cuando presiono la S, pero las S no desaparecen del fichero, se van agregando en la proxima linea y asi..

Comment: @Lorthas o tal vez, también puede ser valido que primero presione S las según el número de lineas pero que al final se marque la S al final. Te diré el ejemplo real, el usuario puede presionar tres letras, S,A,D si presiona la S se marcará al final, lo mismo con la A y con la D. Creí que con una sola letra seria suficiente para defenderme pero me ha dado más dificultad de lo que pensaba...

Comment: Ya estaba tan oxidado que no me acordaba.
No es posible ejecutar una sentencia php basandote en una condición de Javascript porque PHP se ejecuta en el servidor independientemente del javascript que es del lado del cliente.
Para cosas muy sencillas se pueden mezclar sin usar ajax, pero para este caso de ejecutar un codigo PHP según una condición de Javascript, haría falta usar Ajax.

Comment: ok, creo que yo tendria que usar ajax, te diré mi lógica, almacenar en un array en javascript una vez cargado el archivo y haciendo todo esto de marcar, y finalmente mandar dicho array en una petición ajax y finalmente que se escrib en el fichero según el array que se genera.

Comment: @Lorthas ya hice lo que necesitaba, y tu primer código fue primordial, lo hice con una petición ajax enviando un array y luego escribiendo en el fichero. escribe la respuesta para seleccionarla como la mejor

Comment: @yavg pero no tengo codigo nuevo que aportar, es el que tenia antes. Si lo has conseguido podrías publicarte una respuesta a ti mismo.
Intento hacer una respuesta según lo que dices si eso.
Logica sería generar el array y hacer uan petición ajax por linea para reescribir el fichero con la letra escrita o escribir solo al final todo el archivo con las lineas con sus letras? Según lo que quieras, pero hacer varias peticiónes puede resultar ineficiente creo.

Comment: te daré como mejor respuesta. publica